# form fields should be disabled but when a button is clicked the form fields and columns should be enabled,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The form fields both rows and columns should be disabled already but when a button is clicked the form fields should be enabled, I have 11 rows and 11 columns. I will specify my code with few rows and columns. It would be nice if someone helps me clearly.. thanks in advance..

```
<table class="auto-style15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<tr>
<td class="auto-style11" rowspan="2" style="width: 70px"><strong>Operation No</strong></td>
<td class="auto-style22" rowspan="2" style="width: 156px"><strong>Fixture No</strong></td>
```

```
<tr>
<td class="auto-style7" style="width: 70px; height: 25px">
<input name="oprno1" type="text" style="width: 70px" /></td>
<td class="auto-style7" style="height: 25px; width: 156px">
<input name="fixno1" style="width: 150px" type="text" /></td>
```

`<input name="Button1" type="button" value="EDIT" class="auto-style12" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'hasInputs' class to your table and add an id to your button.  Then it's a simple matter of disabling all input fields inside the table on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.hasInputs').find('input').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

and enabling them on click.

```
$('#btnEdit').on('click', function() {
   $('.hasInputs').find('input').prop('disabled', false); 
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HGsW9/1/)

Also, [here is a version](http://jsfiddle.net/HGsW9/2/) with an additional cancel button that toggles the fields.  You could add a "save" button with similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean excactly but this can maybe help you:

jQuery

```
$('.auto-style12').click(function(){ // . is the class selector # for ids
    $(input).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

then you only add `disabled` to every `input`.